# Why doesn't CodenameOne Picker show chosen list items after GUI Builder?

Tags: codenameone

I am beginning to learn cn1 and am having a bit of an issue in the new GUI builder. It seems that when I add list items (text) to a picker in the GUI builder and save, they do not appear afterwords in the simulator.

If I go back to the GUI builder, they are still under listed items.

Does this mean the GUI build is only the face of the app, and all items must be added later in code, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Reading this again I might have misunderstood the question. If you have screenshots you can add it can help clarify what you are seeing...

Comment: Hi : https://imgur.com/a/kWuGBrl

What you'll see is at the bottom left of the second image, it does actually have values via builder. On the top image you'll see those values are not added as options, and a default ... as added first.

Comment: Thanks, I totally misunderstood the question. It was a bug that we just fixed. See the revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

I see the problem, it's a regression in the `Picker` class. It was caused because of a fix to a different problem. I fixed this in this commit https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/03f82ece7500d4ad57c8f30825fb401431adf798

The fix will be available next week. In the meantime as a workaround you can go into the source code of the form. You would need to expand folded code if it's folded and you would see code similar to this:

```
gui_Picker.setPropertyValue("Strings", new String[]{"Red", "Green", "Blue", "Yellow"});
gui_Picker.setType(4);
```

Just copy the `setPropertyValue` line and paste it in the second constructor under the `initGuiBuilderComponents(resourceObjectInstance);` line.

The bug is that the `setType` call erases the value.